# search for a value in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
phone_numbers = {"abbie": "(860) 123-4535", "beverly": "(901) 454-3241",
                 "james": "(212) 567-8149", "thomas": "(795) 342-9145"}
```

Write a function that will look up a phone number given a name. Here is a printout of one of my runs:

```
problem3_5("james")
(212) 567-8149
```

Now i write the `for` loop, and when I put "james" in, it prints the whole values, so I did this:

```
def problem3_5(name):
    for x in phone_numbers["james"]:         
        print(x, end="")
```

But they said that the grader produced too few lines. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please reformat the question so its more legible. Also, you set `end=""` which means the trailing newline isn't getting printed. Could this be your issue? Also, why you need a for loop?

Comment: it prints fine and gets the phone number, but the grader didn't like it. is there any other ways to search for a certain value in the items?! please help!

Answer (score 0):

Searching for a value in a dictionary is very simple. You simply need to index into with the proper key. This is not like a list or tuple where the program would probably have to search all of the data for a match. See the program below. It demonstrates how find things in a dictionary and will hopefully get you going in the right direction.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
def main():
    phone_numbers = dict(
        abbie='(860) 123-4535',
        beverly='(901) 454-3241',
        james='(212) 567-8149',
        thomas='(795) 342-9145'
    )
    name = input('Whose number do you want? ')
    number = phone_numbers[name.lower()]
    answer = 'The number of {} is {}.'.format(name.capitalize(), number)
    print(answer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What is not the answer? The example up above is not supposed to necessarily solve your specific problem. Its purpose is to teach you how you can solve your own problem by following a pattern.